# How to modify a column name in a table when printing the page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser

I have implemented a sortable table using the method described in [RailsCasts 228](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns).
The tables are working and have this appearance:

[image]

But when I print the page (Ctrl + P), the print looks like this:

[image]

Apparently it's printing the description and link.
The lines of code from the html.erb that calls the funcion sortable are like this:

```
 <th><%= sortable("name", t("map.contacts.list.name")) %></th>
```

And the sortable function:

```
    def sortable(column, title = nil)
      title ||= column.titleize
      direction = sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      link_to title, {:filter => request.query_parameters['filter'], :sort => column, :direction =>direction}
    end
```

The table's headers source look like this when the browser render it:

```
<th><a href="/map/generate_list?direction=desc&amp;filter%5Bbirthday_end%5D=&amp;filter%5Bbirthday_init%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_at_end%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_at_init%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_by%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_by_id%5D=&amp;filter%5Bfilter_by_age%5D=0&amp;filter%5Bgender%5D=both&amp;filter%5Bmax_age%5D=65&amp;filter%5Bmin_age%5D=0&amp;filter%5Bstate%5D=&amp;filter%5Btag%5D=&amp;filter%5Btype%5D=both&amp;filter%5Buser_latitude%5D=-26.8257636&amp;filter%5Buser_longitude%5D=-49.2604414&amp;sort=name">Nome</a></th>
```

Well, does anyone have any idea why this happens and how it gets this bug?

Comment: What does the table's source look like once the browser has rendered? (Right Click > View Source)

Comment: @Wes Foster, the header part of the table looks like this:  
<th><a href="/map/generate_list?direction=desc&amp;filter%5Bbirthday_end%5D=&amp;filter%5Bbirthday_init%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_at_end%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_at_init%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_by%5D=&amp;filter%5Bcreated_by_id%5D=&amp;filter%5Bfilter_by_age%5D=0&amp;filter%5Bgender%5D=both&amp;filter%5Bmax_age%5D=65&amp;filter%5Bmin_age%5D=0&amp;filter%5Bstate%5D=&amp;filter%5Btag%5D=&amp;filter%5Btype%5D=both&amp;filter%5Buser_latitude%5D=-26.8257636&amp;filter%5Buser_longitude%5D=-49.2604414&amp;sort=name">Nome</a></th>

Comment: Please edit your question to add code

Comment: Using the browser to view the source isn't entirely accurate. Browsers do fixups to bad HTML to be able to display something to the user, glossing over many problems. It's better to use curl or even OpenURI to read the page and look at it directly outside a browser.

Comment: That the printer output is different than the rendered page doesn't look like a Ruby question, it's a browser or HTML question. Ruby's involvement in the problem ended once the page was emitted and sent to the browser. Since you say the page looks like you want in the browser, Ruby did it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mainly use chrome and I've noticed it throws in the URL for links that get printed. Sortable tables usually have links in the heading and the path appears to be getting printed by your friendly browser. You might look at a print stylesheet:

```
.visable-print {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
    .hidden-print {
        display: none;
    }
    .visable-print {
        display: inline !important;
    }
}
```

You essentially want to hide the part of the table with a link and replace replace it with just the name for printing when the media query is for print.

Comment: I searched for alternatives and couldn't find anything better than yours, but in my opinion this a bug of chrome, the browser shouldn't be printing the href from the <a> tags.